# Return subset elements of list by condition (include string) python pandas

Tags: pandas, list, if-statement

Assuming I'm dealing with this dataframe:

| Element List |
| --- |
| [123, 1234, abc-123, abc-1234] |
| [abc-321] |
| nan |
| ... |

As you may recognize, '[]' represents the data type in 'Element List' column is list

My desired output should be like this:

| Element List | abc | Others |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [123, 1234, abc-123, abc-1234] | [abc-123, abc-1234] | [123,1234] |
| [abc-321] | [abc-321] | nan |
| nan | nan | nan |
| ... | ... | ... |

The point is how to extract the subset of list by a condition (like include, or is in) and list it in different columns. Here, 'abc' column includes the subset that includes abc string, and 'Others' column includes the complement of selected subset of list.

Have no idea to deal with the list data type in a column... Sorry for very naive question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
mask = pd.notna(df["Element List"])

df[["abc", "Others"]] = df.loc[mask, "Element List"].apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(
        {
            "abc": [v for v in x if v.startswith("abc")] or np.nan,
            "Others": [v for v in x if not v.startswith("abc")] or np.nan,
        }
    )
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                     Element List                  abc       Others
0  [123, 1234, abc-123, abc-1234]  [abc-123, abc-1234]  [123, 1234]
1                       [abc-321]            [abc-321]          NaN
2                             NaN                  NaN          NaN
```

Comment: I tried to solve this similar to you. I wrote a little helper function which checks if element is np.nan, else divides the list into the parts with `abc` and those without. The function always returns 2 elements (each a list or np.nan). I thought it works like tuple unpacking (2 return values for 2 new columns) so next step was: `df[['abc', 'other']] = df['Element_List'].apply(my_func)`. I get the error `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key` but I'm not able to figure out what I'm missing here. Do you have a little hint for me,maybe?

Comment: oh, solved it by myself. If i wrap my return statements in with `pd.Series` it works....still don't quite get it tbh.

Comment: Great comments. And just for others, you can get rid of the comma at the end of line#7.

Comment: @pythong being sarcastic or serious?

Comment: @Rabinzel that was for Andrej Kesely. Anyway thanks for the comments.